# How to the path from a file input tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access file path obtained from browsing file using input tag. I want to display the path.

Comment: eh, darn, clicked the wrong duplicate link, but this is a duplicate [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write the Path of a file to upload in a text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640082/how-to-write-the-path-of-a-file-to-upload-in-a-text-box)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use any HTML or JavaScript API to get the file's path in input\[type=file\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084133/can-i-use-any-html-or-javascript-api-to-get-the-files-path-in-inputtype-file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery:

```
<input type="file" id="input" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input").on("change", function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I.e. $(this).val() contains the file path.

Here is a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/uwaf2/

Answer (score 0):

From

[Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path)

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

> ```
> var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();
> ```
>
> or you could just do (because it's always C:\fakepath that is added
>   for security reasons):
>
> ```
> var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '')
> ```

[Full path from file input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery)

You cannot read the full file path in js due to security reasons.

Comment: Is it "C:\fakepath\" on platforms other than Windows? I'd find it odd to see that path on Linux or Mac.